# How do I change the filename_format of picture to rostime?

Tags: ros, image-view, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All:

At present the Bag file change a picture file. File name are frame000001,frame000002......
How do I change the  filename_format of picture to rostime?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263042/how-do-i-change-the--filename_format-of-picture-to-rostime?/) by [lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30598/lin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[link](http://wiki.ros.org/image_view) maybe can help you

> have you finished it?

---

Originally posted by [alexchauncy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35166/alexchauncy/) with karma: 16 on 2018-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0